# Javascript - Duplication of object property setting

Tags: javascript, object

I am very new to Javascript and have looked at someone elses code to try and work out what it does. I have seen the following, and can't understand why 'total' has been set twice using different notation. Am I being really dense here? The code is:

```
contents = {
apples : 0,
oranges : 0,
bananas : 0,
grapes : 0,
peach : 0,
total : function() {return this.apples+this.oranges+this.bananas+this.grapes+this.peach;}
};

contents.total = function() {return this.apples+this.oranges+this.bananas+this.grapes+this.peach;};
```

I know that contents.total is outside of making the object, but why set the property immediately after if it's already set to the same thing?

Comment: No valid reason.

Comment: No, you're not being dense. This code is weird, one of the two lines is indeed superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

If these statements are immediately subsequent, there is no obvious reason to re-assign the same value to the total attribute. However, if the statements are interleaved by others, it may be that the instruction is updating the contents of the **total** attribute.